# React-Virtualized : CellRender goes under next Row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm build app with React-virtualized Table. 
I added some custom cell render inside each Row. Like Label, or some Img.

Everything works great, but there's a weird behavior.

Inside one cell, I added a simple Dropdown to let user choose some value.
Actually, my dropdown render go UNDER the next row. After a click, the dropdown expand and keep under next row.

Is there something that I missed ? Is it normal behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown menu is getting clipped by the parent row's `overflow: hidden` style. (It may also be obscured by the following row's `background-color` if you've set one.)

Here's an example of what I'm talking about wrt clipping:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9iMzJh?p=preview

I suggest using something [react-portal](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal) to avoid clipping problems. I've used this before with `Table` and have been pretty happy with it.

Comment: can you provide an example of this, please?